# How to render model a single row text area for TextField in django admin form

Tags: django-forms, django-admin, django-4.0

I have a Django 4.0 model that includes some `TextField` fields. These are displayed in large text box in the corresponding admin form. How do I reduce the displayed size of a text field in a django admin form, e.g. to just one row?

I have tried setting the widgets dictionary on the form with a Textarea that has the number of rows and cols explictly set, as listed below. However this does not seem to work?

**Model**

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    """
    Product
    """

    id = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    attributes = models.TextField()
```

**Form and admin**

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        exclude = ("id",)

    widgets = {
        "attributes": Textarea(attrs={"cols": 30, "rows": 1})
    }

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_per_page = 10
    form = ProductForm
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "forms." before calling the widget...

Change:

```
widgets = {
        "attributes": Textarea(attrs={"cols": 30, "rows": 1})
    }
```

To:

```
    widgets = {
        "attributes": forms.Textarea(attrs={"cols": 30, "rows": 1})
    }
```

(Not tested) Hope this helps :-)

Comment: tried it - didn't work.

Comment: @VaidøtasI. perhaps share a code snippet of your form. I have since tested and used this and it works for me.